# Session ID Creating 404 Errors

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, url-parameters

**Problem:**

- Website contains URLs with parameters
- Session ID gets inserted into URLs when Googlebot crawls page with parameter (sorting) options
- Session ID is created and then expires, creating a 404 in Google WMT
- *I am unable to remove session IDs in URLs given the circumstances in the workplace

**Example URL:**

`example.com/category/product/;jsessionid=+03NVNOPUryFcZ0c169r8txU.prod-14?f=p%3A0-10%2C2000-2500%2C25-50%2C400-500%2C50-75%2C500-750;r%3A0%2C4`

**Parameter Functions:**

- `f=p`: price
- `r`: rating
- `p=`: pagination

**Webmaster Tool Configuration:**

- `f` defined as parameter that narrows - no urls should be crawled
- `p` defined as parameter that paginates - let Googlebot decide
- `jsessionid` defined as parameter that is a representative url - no urls getting picked up by WMT

**Questions:**

1. If no URLs are to be crawled containing `f` parameter, why are they still getting crawled?
2. Regarding question 1, is it because the `p` parameter is overriding?
3. Should I set the `jsessionid` parameter as ";jsessionid" instead of "jsessionid"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is malformed, `jsessionid` isn't a parameter, it's being read as a route. If `jsessionid`, `f`, and `r` are all supposed to be parameters, your URL should look like this:

`example.com/category/product?jsessionid=+03NVNOPUryFcZ0c169r8txU.prod-14&f=p%3A0-10%2C2000-2500%2C25-50%2C400-500%2C50-75%2C500-750&r=%3A0%2C4`

Comment: Probably need an `=` after the `r` as well.

Comment: I'm not saying jsessionid is a parameter, but in Google's Search Console, it's handled under the URL Parameters section.

When adding a new parameter, you get a field to input the parameter, and then a secondary dropdown list: "Does this parameter change page content seen by the user?"

If you select No, then the following message appears: 

Select this option if this parameter can be set to any value without changing the page content. For example, select this option if the parameter is a session ID. If many URLs differ only in this parameter, Googlebot will crawl one representative URL.

Comment: @w3d oops, edited and added

Comment: @czmudzin that doesn't make any sense, it's either a parameter or a route, there aren't any other options and you mentioned that it was a parameter a few times

Comment: @czmudzin The problem with the original URL is that `jsessionid` is not a URL parameter, it is simply part of the URL path (your application may be treating this differently). You can't forcefully tell Google that some arbitrary string is a URL parameter when it is not. Google will not see it as a URL parameter and the rule in Google's Search Console will effectively be ignored. As Chris mentions, it's either a parameter or it's not.